# pgloader показывает, что импортировал, но нет таблиц

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Хочу импортировать базу данных с Mysql на PostgresSQL. Использую pgloader. Запускаю командой

```
pgloader mysql://mysql_username:"password"@localhost/mysqlbdname postgresql://postgres_username:'password'@127.0.0.1/postgresdbname
```

По результатам показывает, что все таблицы прочитаны и импортированы, ошибок 0. Однако, когда захожу в postgres и запрашиваю таблицы командой \dt, выдает "Отношения не найдены."
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: а ты точно в `postgresdbname` смотришь? `\c postgresdbname `

Comment: Да, точно смотрю эту базу)

Comment: а если `\dt *.*`? Кроме pg_catalog и information_schema есть что?

Comment: Да, есть, в схемах - postgresdbname, в именах все таблицы которые должны быть.

Comment: ну значит туда данные и скопировал pgloader. Как ему указать схему - надо искать, не знаком с этой софтиной.

Comment: Эээ... а собственно куда он скопировал, то данные?) Только начал разбираться с данной БД

Comment: Postgresql умеет такую штуку как schema: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-schemas.html У mysql аналога нет. Дополнительный уровень пространства имён, позволяющий логически группировать объекты в базе.